# How to set UIBarButtonSystemItem in self class (Swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I made a class for a bar button item to use it in all `view controllers`

```
import UIKit

class SearchBarItem: UIBarButtonItem {
    let searchBarItemImage = UIBarButtonSystemItem.Search

    required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.init()
        self.title = "AnyText" /// This one working and Title will changed

    }

}
```

I need set `SearchBarItem` image to `UIBarButtonSystemItem.Search`

I should be something like this:

```
self.barButtonSystemItem = UIBarButtonSystemItem.Search
```

------------------------ Let me explain

I want to make a class to set in identity inspector of "Bar Button Item" all view controllers in my project.

This class should customize "Bar Button Item"s for exam change image to UIBarButtonSystemItem.Search .

Some I made `SearchBarItem: UIBarButtonItem class`, I can change Title of "Bar Button Item"s with this convenience init:

```
required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.init()
    self.title = "AnyText"
}
```

But It's not what I need. I need to change image to a magnify. So I searched and find out that magnify image is in `UIBarButtonSystemItem` enum with `.Search` key

My question is: How can I set `UIBarButtonSystemItem.Search` in initialization of SearchBarItem class ?

Comment: Please elaborate you want help for what? What is your issue?

Comment: @user345095, I edit question. take a look

Answer (score 0):

I found another way:
I made a class to control `Navigation Items` and It's the solution for me:

```
import UIKit

class NavigationItems: UINavigationItem {

    convenience required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        self.init()
        let searchBtn = UIBarButtonItem.init(barButtonSystemItem: .Search, target: nil, action: "SearchNavClick")
        self.rightBarButtonItem = searchBtn
    }

}
```

And changed navigation items identify inspector class to this new class `(NavigationItems)` .